# macOS Catalinaへのアップデートができない

Tags: macos

macOS Mojava 10.14.6をmacOS Catalinaにアップデートしようと思いましたが、
「最新の状態です」(Your Mac is up to date)となりCatalinaにアップデートできません。
こちらの回避方法をご教示いただけますでしょうか。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

使用しているmacは2012以降のmac book air(11-inch,Mid 2013)となりますのでcatalinaには対応しております。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下記2点は実行済みです。
・app storeからcatalinaを直接ダウンロード
→結論：下記のようになり失敗
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
↓
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
↓
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
・OSの再インストール
下記URLを参考にOS再インストールを行いましたが「最新の状態です」は回避されずに失敗。
https://www.sin-space.com/entry/macos-re-install

Answer (score 1):

同様質問をApple Support Community でも行い、
下記で解決いたしました！

https://discussionsjapan.apple.com/thread/251227020

> ターミナルを開いて `softwareupdate --reset-ignored` をコピー＆ペーストしてリターンキーを押してください。

Answer (score 0):

直接の回答ではありませんが以下のリンクが参考になるかもしれません。

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250740432#251506736022

お住まいは日本ですか? ネットワークがVPNかなにかを通っていないでしょうか?
DNS設定なども関係していそうな感じです。